# Relation between the number of router solicitations/second and hosts coming into the network

Tags: networking, network-protocols, ipv6

I have read in a book that as soon as a host enters a network, it sends out the Router Solicitation so that it can build up its router list. Does all the hosts behave like that in a network? Are there any cases where a host enters a network and waits for unsolicited Router Advertisement instead of sending out a router Solicitation to learn about router and configure itself?(in ipv6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Depends on the host'... They probably will send out Router Solicitations, but they could just wait for a Router Advertisement to come by. The most common operating systems like Windows, Mac OS and Linux will send them.

Comment: Are you sure of it? I have to form a relation between the router solicitations being generated per second and hosts entering the network per second for the purpose of benchmarking. Is there any other case where hosts sends out router solicitations other than when they enter a network?

Comment: That is completely implementation dependent. The relation between the router solicitations being generated per second and hosts entering the network per second that you are looking for is fictional. It might work, but it will probably be wrong...